# Why is this new mapping not taking effect when creating index in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I'm using elasticsearch 1.5.0.

I create a new index the following way and download some tweets into the new index OK, but when I look at the actual mapping it is not using this mapping, but seems to have tried to figure out the mapping itself. What am I doing wrong here?

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/tweets' -d '
{
  "tweets" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "tweet" : {
      "properties" : {
          "created_at" : {
            "type" : "date",
            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
          },
          "day" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "favorite_count" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "hashtags" : {
            "properties" : {
              "indices" : {
              "type" : "integer"
          },
          "text" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "analyzed",
            "analyzer" : "standard"
          }
        }
      },
        "id_str" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "in_reply_to_screen_name" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        "month" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        },
        "screen_name" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        "text" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "index" : "analyzed",
          "analyzer" : "standard"
        },
        "urls" : {
          "properties" : {
            "display_url" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "expanded_url" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "indices" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "url" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "index" : "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "user_mentions" : {
          "properties" : {
            "id" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "id_str" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "indices" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "name" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "screen_name" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "index" : "not_analayzed"
            }
          }
        },
        "year" : {
          "type" : "integer"
        }
       }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

When I have tested to download some tweets into the index and check the mapping I get:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/tweets/_mapping/tweet?pretty'

{
"tweets" : {
  "mappings" : {
    "tweet" : {
      "properties" : {
        "created_at" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "day" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "favorite_count" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "hashtags" : {
          "properties" : {
            "indices" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "text" : {
              "type" : "string"
            }
          }
        },
        "id_str" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "in_reply_to_screen_name" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "month" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "screen_name" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "text" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "urls" : {
          "properties" : {
            "display_url" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "expanded_url" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "indices" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "url" : {
              "type" : "string"
            }
          }
        },
        "user_mentions" : {
          "properties" : {
            "id" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "id_str" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "indices" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "name" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "screen_name" : {
              "type" : "string"
            }
          }
        },
        "year" : {
          "type" : "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

When I check the mapping for the index tweets I get the following result, before I index any tweets into it:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/tweets/_mapping?pretty'
{
  "tweets" : {
    "mappings" : { }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you interrogating the mapping immediately after posting this and finding that it differs? What does the mapping that is returned look like?

Comment: I've updated the question with the response I get after testing to download some tweets into the index.

Comment: That's going to include dynamic mappings. What is the mapping immediately after you post your index create?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you possibly notice the error being returned from your post attempting to create the index? Under "screen_name" you have "not_analayzed". Change that to "not_analyzed" and you'll be fine.